# Suitable storage method for huge amount of data

Tags: mapreduce, rdbms, bigdata

what kind of storage do you recommend for very huge amount of data? (≈ 50 milions records per day). Is this proper situation for systems like Hadoop or RDBMS is still sufficient for this purpose?

Comment: How long are you planning to keep your data? How complex is the schema? Is it pretty much a star schema with a single large fact table and a bunch of small(-ish) dimension tables? What kinds of queries are you going to perfrom on your data? Would they involve entire tables or only a date-range specific data (daily, weekly, monthly, etc.)?

Comment: Raw data need to be preprocessed, parsed and aggregated into report data. Reports will not be deleted, raw data will be deleted after processing. Reports will saved as numerical data. Queries - primary there will be statistical queries (avg, sum, min, max) for particular data range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the amount of data you are describing, you might indeed be pushing into the Big Data terrirtory. Based on the amount of the details you provided, I would suggest loading raw data into Hadoop cluster, running map/reduce jobs to parse it and to load into date-based directories. You can then define an external Hive table partitioned by date (daily? weekly?) mapped to the results of your map/reduce jobs.

Next step would depend on the complexity of your reports and needed response time. If you can easily express them in SQL, you can just run queries on your Hive table. If they are more elaborated, you might have to write custom map/reduce jobs. Many suggest Pig for it, but I am personally more comforatble with the straight Java.

If you don't care about the response time of the reports, you can run them on-demand. If you care, but open to wait for the results for, say, tens of seconds or a few minutes, you can store report results also in Hive. If you want your reports to show up fast, say, in web-based or mobile UI, you might want to store the report data in a relational database.

Comment: For now when we work on prototype and there is no such huge amount of data, data is stored in relational database. In production it won't be possible, now I am thinking about future data flow in production usage - what do you recommend if report should be served via web-base UI and speed will be important? I have an idea to store raw data in Hadoop and processed data store in a relational database. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: "store raw data in Hadoop and processed data store in a relational database" - pretty much summarises my answer. If you can express your summarization as SQL queries, consider querying data in Hadoop using Hive. I like writing map/reduce in Java, but if I can express summary in a single SQL statement, there's no question which way to go.